32 обучающихся или 32 обучающегося
Скажите, как правильно: 32 обучающихся или 32 обучающегося? Правильно ли составлена фраза "перевести 31 обучающегося в 5 класс"?

Приветствую вас, Гаяне! Определитесь, пожалуйста, — 32 или 31?

Нужно перевести тридцать одного ученика в 5-ый класс. Нет смысла перегружать определениями.

Но если насчёт склонения, то 31-ого(21,41) обучающегося, но 32 (33, 34,.., 40 и тп.) обучающихся. Кроме тех, кто на один заканчивается.

А что тут определяться?  Оба варианта интересны, да только ни одного ответа нет.

• Сначала посмотрим в словаре управления:
перевести (кого/что) — назначить на другое место, должность, поставить в другие условия. Перевести на должность инженера. Перевести ученика в следующий класс. Перевести на другой оклад.
То есть нужен винительный падеж.
• Числительное один изменяется по родам (один лимон, одна груша, одно яблоко) и по числам (связь — согласование; форма одни употребляется с существительными только множественного числа или с теми, которые обозначают парные предметы: одни ножницы, одни бусы).
Правильно:
перевести 31 (тридцать одного) обучающегося, видеть 31 (тридцать одну) летящую птицу.

При существительных мужского и среднего рода, зависящих от числительных два, три, четыре (а также от составных числительных, оканчивающихся на указанные цифры), определение, находящееся между числительным и существительным, в современном языке ставится, как правило, в форме родительного падежа множественного числа: два высоких дома, три больших окна, двадцать четыре деревянных стола.

При использовании субстантивированного причастия (оно употребляется как существительное) это правило сохраняется.
Правильно:
перевести 32 обучающихся, вижу 32 летящих.
О склонении числительных
§193. Определение при существительном, зависящем от числительных два, три, четыре

Правильно: тридцать один обучающийся (ученик), тридцать два обучающихся (ученика).
Перевести тридцать два обучающихся (ученика), тридцать одного обучающегося (ученика) в пятый класс.
Пояснение
Что надо знать?

Субстантивированные прилагательные и причастия используются в форме мн. числа: как и ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЯ в числовых оборотах, но не как существительные. Информация из Грамматики-80.

Числительное ОДИН всегда согласуется в числе со стоящим рядом словом. Это особое числительное с падежными окончаниями существительных (И.п. и В.п.) и прилагательных (в остальных падежах). Поэтому "один" может только согласоваться  с существительным во всех падежах.


